# warning in texmaker keeps on repeating

Tags: texmaker

I have a template presentation and in this presentation there is a line

```
\author{Lal Upendra Pratap Singh \\2014AN-12}
```

When I ran PDFLatex command in TexMaker, I got the following warning

```
Tokens not allowed in the PDF string(PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref) removing '\\'
```

Then I removed the \ and ran PDFLatex again. The warning is not gone. Also, when I try to change code, I am not seeing the results in the generated PDF. I used to run PDFLatex and then ViewPDF command.

Do I need to install some other software also? I have only installed TexMaker. I somewhere read that Miketex and Bibtex are also required. Is it  true?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Is the linenumber from you warning the same as your quoted code? Could there be other instances of `\\`? Also, you specify that you removed `\`, did you remove both of them `\\`, leaving the code to: `\author{Lal Upendra Pratap Singh \\2014AN-12}`? You seem to already have installed `MikTex` or atleast some kind of destibution, so you don't need anything more. `BibTex` would only be required if you use `bibliography`, and you most likely have it installed already.

Comment: To help you further it would help a lot if you provided an [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)

Comment: line number of warning is same as the quoted code; also I removed both the  backslashes . I ran the same code in Kile, it worked without any errors